# How to capture kobject_uevent using C program?

Tags: c, events, linux-kernel

I have created `/dev/ttyACM0` port in my target for gps connection. Due to some reason this port is disconnecting in between when target is running. Whenever disconnection happen I will get `kobject-uevent` and right not I am capturing this event using netlink sample program as follow.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <linux/netlink.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <linux/netlink.h>

#define NETLINK_TEST    17
#define MYGROUP         1

#define MAX_PAYLOAD 1024  /* maximum payload size*/
struct sockaddr_nl src_addr, dest_addr;
struct nlmsghdr *nlh = NULL;
struct iovec iov;
int sock_fd;
struct msghdr msg;

int main()
{
    int ret, fd;
    char *temp;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyACM1", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Unable to open port\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Creating socket\n");
    sock_fd=socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT);
    if(sock_fd<0) {
        printf("Socket creating failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(src_addr));
    src_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    src_addr.nl_pid = getpid();  /* self pid */
    src_addr.nl_groups = MYGROUP;
    /* interested in group 1<<0 */
    ret = bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr,
            sizeof(src_addr));
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("Bind Failed\n");
        perror("bind:");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    dest_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    dest_addr.nl_pid = 0;   /* For Linux Kernel */
    dest_addr.nl_groups = 0; /* unicast */

memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
dest_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
dest_addr.nl_pid = 0;   /* For Linux Kernel */
dest_addr.nl_groups = 0; /* unicast */

    nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)malloc(NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    memset(nlh, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    nlh->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD);
    nlh->nlmsg_flags = 0;
    iov.iov_base = (void *)nlh;
    iov.iov_len = nlh->nlmsg_len;
    msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dest_addr);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    printf("Waiting for message from kernel\n");
    /* Read message from kernel */
    while (1) {
        recvmsg(sock_fd, &msg, 0);
        temp = strstr(NLMSG_DATA(nlh), "tty/ttyACM1");
        printf("Received message payload: %s\n", temp);
    }
    close(sock_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

using this program I am getting below output.

```
Received message payload: 0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/tty/ttyACM1
```

which is the path of the device for which disconnect happen. But when I check `/lib/kobject_uevent.c` code I have seen it is sending *action_string* with device path which is in my case *remove*.

If I want to capture this `action_string` how can I capture it?

Comment: firstly try and see if you get events using "udevadm  monitor" , here is an example using libudev http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/udev_example.c

Comment: I am getting events using the program mention above. So i think I no need to check with "udevadm monitor".

But thank you for suggesting this due to this I went through the libudev code and found out how they are extracting full message from netlink socket and same method i followed and I am also getting uevent with action_string.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Due to some research and suggestion by Prabhakar in comment I came to know we have to use libudev.so libraries for getting the proper uevent in user space.

But for testing purpose I went through libudev source code and found out libudev also captures uevent using netlink. Only the difference in libudev code is it uses union{} which contain 'struct nlmsghdr' and 'char buf[SIZE]'. So data which is coming in nlmsghdr struct we can print using buf.

So as a Hack I used union instead of "struct nlmsghdr *nlh" and created one raw buffer inside that union along with this structure as below

```
union {
    struct nlmsghdr nlh;
    char raw[8192];
} buf;
```

Full working program after this changes is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>

#define NETLINK_TEST    17
#define MYGROUP         1

#define MAX_PAYLOAD 1024  /* maximum payload size*/
struct sockaddr_nl src_addr, dest_addr;
union {
    struct nlmsghdr nlh;
    char raw[8192];
} buf;
struct iovec iov;
int sock_fd;
struct msghdr msg;

int main() 
{
    int ret, fd, i;
    char *event_buf;
    char action[50];
#if 1
    fd = open("/dev/ttyACM1", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Unable to open port\n");
        return -1;
    }
#endif
    printf("Creating socket\n");
    sock_fd=socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT);
    if(sock_fd<0) {
        printf("Socket creating failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(src_addr));
    src_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    src_addr.nl_pid = getpid();  /* self pid */
    src_addr.nl_groups = MYGROUP;
    /* interested in group 1<<0 */
    ret = bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr,
            sizeof(src_addr));
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("Bind Failed\n");
        perror("bind:");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    dest_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    dest_addr.nl_pid = 0;   /* For Linux Kernel */
    dest_addr.nl_groups = 0; /* unicast */

    memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    iov.iov_base = &buf;
    iov.iov_len = sizeof(buf);
    msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dest_addr);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
#if 1
    /* Read message from kernel */
    while (1) {
        recvmsg(sock_fd, &msg, 0);
        if (strstr(buf.raw, "/tty/ttyACM1") != NULL) {
            event_buf = buf.raw;
            for (i = 0; event_buf[i] != '@'; i++)
                action[i] = event_buf[i];
            action[i] = '\0';
            printf("ACTION = %s\n", action);
            if ((strcmp(action, "remove")) == 0) {
                close(fd);
                printf("ACM port closed\n");
            }
        }
    }
end:
    close(sock_fd);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Here in buf.raw i am getting uevent message with action_string. For Example:

```
remove@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/tty/ttyACM2
```

where "remove" is action string and rest of the string after '@' is device path for that event.